# How to make web client choose the right server in different location?

Tags: web-server, proxy, load-balancing, web-hosting, web-applications

I have two web servers, one is Located in Europe, and another is Located in Asia, both of them have the same web application. My question is , how can I make my website or mobile app choose the right server, the Asia users  connect to the Asia Server, and the Europe users connect to the Europe Server ?

I have tried load balancing, proxy in the server side, but they do not work.

And I think maybe I can do it in the client side, just let the client choose the right server base on their position?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Research in Haproxy: 
1. https://lnk.fahad.space/2a4waGb
2. https://lnk.fahad.space/2a4wMvk

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of geo-aware DNS service, so that DNS requests coming from Asia get the IP address of the Asia-based server and then connect directly to that, and likewise for the European users.

You may be able to do this in your DNS server - is your DNS hosted by you or others?

Answer (score -1):

Any small vm acting as reverse proxy sould do. Just use nginx with GEOIP module. Here a nice tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-nginx-as-a-global-traffic-director-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Then you point your dns to this vm and thia vm will then act as traffic director